# How to install Cordova plugins on Meteor 1.3

Tags: node.js, cordova, meteor

I am trying to install a Mapbox plugin on my meteor 1.3 Cordova app.  In 1.3 the recommendation is to install with npm so I went looking for an npm package and found one mentioned on the Mapbox website.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mapbox#3-installation

The install notes give the install line:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=your.access.token
```

My first attempt was to try meteor add with roughly the same syntax

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-mapbox@https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=your.access.token
```

This gave me the fairly predictable result:

```
--variable: unknown option.
```

I then tried it out without the variable flag and got:

```
cordova-plugin-mapbox: Meteor requires either an exact version (e.g. cordova-plugin-mapbox@1.0.0), a Git URL with a SHA reference, or a local path.
```

What is the right approach to installing cordova plugins in Meteor 1.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the NPM registry, so you only need to provide a version (as the example in your error output suggests):

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-mapbox@1.1.2
```

The variable needs to be supplied in your mobile-config.js in your meteor folder

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova-plugin-mapbox', { ACCESS_TOKEN: 'ABCDEF12345' });
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be something like that, but with the changes to 1.3 its sometimes hard to figure out what is current and reliable information.